# How to run database in localhost using pgAdmin with docker instance?

Tags: ruby, postgresql, macos, docker, pgadmin

This is my docker-compose, and a want to open database in localhost with pgAdmin (I'm using MacOS), someone can help-me?

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mdillon/postgis:9.4
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_DB=mytestapp_development
     - POSTGRES_USER=root
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root

  dbtest:
    image: mdillon/postgis:9.4
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_DB=mytestapp_test
     - POSTGRES_USER=root
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root

  web:
    depends_on:
     - db
     - dbtest
    build: .
    command: bin/rails s --port 3000 --binding 0.0.0.0
    volumes:
     - .:/app
```

Comment: "localhost" and Docker interact in subtle ways; can you say where you want pgAdmin to be running using different terminology?  What issues are you actually running into?  Do you have a Dockerfile for your "web" container, if it's relevant?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Mac, but on linux, I need to edit the file config.inc.php, on /etc/phpmyadmin, then change the

/* Server parameters */

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'your ip docker container';

Then restart phpmyadmin